# Tagging and referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I am working in my final degree project and I have to reference some parts of the document (just a few paragraphs) where I don't understand something for my tutor to help me with. I want to create a special tagging, and, at the beginning of the document, reference those tags to help my tutor finding the parts in trouble. Is there any package that can help me do it?

I can use the classic `\label` and `\ref` method but that may be not the best idea as I have to label each of those paragraphs, then reference it at the beginning of the text and when I correct it I have to banish those labels and refs. So I wanted to know if there exists an easier way to do it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sounds as if you want one of the to do packages e.g. todonotes.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try inline comments with the `\todonotes` package. e.g.:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}

\begin{document}

%%% Here is your document

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \todo{Please help me here}. 
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, 
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```